# Cifrado Cesar con desplazamineto n

Tags: c++

Soy un poco nuevo en programacion. Hice este programa, por si no conocen el cifrado Cesar se dezplaza posiciones n en el alfabeto para remplazar una frase/mensaje.

Por ejemplo.

Hola mundo, con 3 desplazamientos deberia ser cambiado por:

Krod pxqgr.

Lo que no se es, como hacer que se imprima
mi void. Pero quiero hacerlo desde el main, no desde el mismo void.

Es posible añadir la impresion en el main?
Dado que siempre lo he hecho direntamente en el void. Siendo una especie de retorno esa impresion.

**Podrian indicarme otro error? Mi Dev C++ no me los esta mostrando.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

 using namespace std;
 
void encriptar(char mensaje[100],int n); 

char ABC [] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
char abc []= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
int n=0; 
 
int main(){ 
 

char cadena[100];
cin.getline(cadena, 100);   
    
cout<<"introduce un numero: "; 
cin>> n;
encriptar (mensaje, n);
cout<< mensaje;
return 0; 
}
```

Por aqui inicia el void que planteo.

```
void encriptar(char mensaje[100], int n){ 

         while (n<0 || n>25){
         ;
        for(int i = 0; mensaje[i]; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<26; j++)
                {
 
                    if ( mensaje[i]==' ')
                        break;
                    if (mensaje[i]==abc[j] && j+ n<26)
                    {
                        mensaje[i] =  abc[j+ n];
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (mensaje[i]==abc[j] && j+ n>=26)
                    {
                        mensaje[i] =  ABC[j+n-26];
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (mensaje[i]==ABC[j] && j+ n<26)
                    {
                        mensaje[i] =  ABC[j+ n];
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (mensaje[i]==ABC[j] && j+ n>=26)
                        {
                            mensaje[i] =  abc[j+ n-26];
                            break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
        
}
```

**No estoy muy seguro de tener mas errores**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estas pasando una variable sin declarar a encriptar:

```
encriptar (mensaje, n);
cout<< mensaje;
```

En lugar de pasar mensaje tienes que pasar cadena.

Puedes imprimirlo en el main sin problemas porque lo que pasas a `encriptar` es un puntero a el array de caracteres.

El unico problema es que no estas encriptando el mensaje. No estoy muy seguro de lo que haces para encriptarlo, pero como la pregunta no es de eso, solo te dejo este ejemplo para que veas que no es problema imprimirlo en el main. Solo tienes que cambiar lo que hace la funcion `encriptar`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

 using namespace std;
 
void encriptar(char mensaje[100] ,int n); 

char ABC [] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
char abc []= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
int n=0; 
 
int main(){ 
    char cadena[100];
    cin.getline(cadena, 100);   
    cout<<"introduce un numero: "; 
    cin>> n;
    encriptar (cadena, n);
    cout<< cadena;
    return 0; 
} 

void encriptar(char mensaje[100], int n){ 
    int i = 0;
    while(mensaje[i] != '\0') {
        mensaje[i] +=n;
        i++;
    }
        
}
```